# SpriteKit: SKShader with custom shader not doing `mix` properly

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, opengl-es-2.0

I am using a custom shader to create a sprite in SpriteKit.

The main part of the shader does this...

```
vec4 col = mix(baseColor, overlayColor, overlayColor.a);
```

The colours I have are something like...

```
baseColor = UIColor(red:0.51, green:0.71, blue:0.88, alpha:1.0)
```

and...

```
overlay = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 0.5)
```

According to everywhere on the internet (links to follow) the blend function I'm using above is the same as a `Normal` blend mode in Photoshop, Pixelmator, Sketch, etc... this should result in the colour...

```
col = UIColor(red:0.75, green:0.85, blue:0.95, alpha:1.00)
```

Which is a bright blue colour. However, what I'm getting is...

```
col = UIColor(red:0.51, green:0.61, blue:0.69, alpha:1.00)
```

Which is a murky grey colour.

You can see what it should look like here... https://thebookofshaders.com/glossary/?search=mix

If you enter the code...

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform float u_time;

vec4 colorA = vec4(0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 1.0);
vec4 colorB = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5);

void main() {
    vec4 color = vec4(0.0);

    // Mix uses pct (a value from 0-1) to
    // mix the two colors
    color = mix(colorA, colorB, colorB.a);
    color.a = 1.0;

    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

The ideal output colour looks like this...

[image]

But it looks like this...

[image]

I’m gonna investigate this more tomorrow. I wish I knew why the output was completely different than everywhere else says it should be.

Comment: Do you get the same color if you do `gl_FragColor = vec4(0.75, 0.85, 0.95, 1.0)`?

Comment: @Reaper I will give it a try this morning. Thanks

Comment: @Reaper so returning that colour was correct. Which then lead me down a path that was able to determine that the colour picked up from our white alpha image wasn't in fact white but was grey. We used a different approach to map the colours and alpha separately that fixed this :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, thanks to @Reaper's comment I started out on a full investigation of what was going wrong with this.

When mixing the hard coded colours in our shader the colour was actually correct.

So it lead me to look at the texture images we were using.

The one that had the white with 50% alpha was definitely white. (not grey).

But... (quirk in the system?) open GL was picking it up as 50% grey with 50% alpha.

And so the mix wasn't actually mixing the correct colours in the first place.

We fixed this by using a 100% alpha image for the colours and a 100% image for the alpha map (black -> white).

By doing this it fixed the problem we were having.